# Angular JS $log and memory leaks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks

I'm reading about memory leaks and I understand that using `console.log()` to write structured objects (not strings) to the console can cause memory leaks. My app user Angular's `$log.log()` to do something similar. Will this leak memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$log` service uses `console.log` internally - from the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/log.js):

> ```
>   var console = $window.console || {},
>       logFn = console[type] || console.log || noop,
>       hasApply = false;
> ```

However, you can disable the console messages using `$logProvider.debugEnabled(false);` whenever you need, so it's safe to use as long as you remember to switch off the debug messages in production.

Comment: Thanks Ori that sounds doable. Is there best practice / workflow for toggling the client-side settings like that? For example, the backend uses environment variables to determine development/production. Do you recommend that I pass a variable into a `<script>` block, or is there a better way to toggle `debugEnabled`?

Comment: I am building a large webapp as well. I think even `console.log` will produce memory leaks, it will produce it in browser's console panel. It has nothing to do with the current browsing tab. If you open Chrome's console, it will fork another process.

Comment: A global production flag is usually what I do, as we have to switch off $log, `$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false)`, and enable/disable other production settings. You can inject it the HTML body using the backend or a build tool, or create a settings.json and integrate it's data with browserify or webpack. The flag loading should be synchronous, and happen before the config phase of the modules.

Comment: @stanleyxu2005 `console.log` saves a reference to the original object, so you can debug it, change it, etc... This sometimes causes memory leaks, as the reference in the console is the only one that preventing the GC from removing the object.

Answer (score 0):

As ori says, turning off log messages in production should negate this as a problem. For messages that you still want in production, I'd recommend logging JSON.stringify().